# How to return a has many object directly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

I’m trying to find a way to return a has many object directly instead of the parent object with the relation  intact

Here is my ProjectExternalTeam model, for which I am looking to return the guests directly (a collection of users)

```
class ProjectExternalTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :guest, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'member_id'
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User', foreign_key:'invited_by_id'
end
```

Right now I am using something like

```
gus = []
gg = ProjectExternalTeam.where(account_id:1)
gg.each do |g| gus.push(g.guest) end
```

With this gus ends up being a collection of users. I feel that there must be some easier way to do this, something like

```
gus = ProjectExternalTeam.where(account_id:1).guests
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to `map`. Using the `&:method` syntax (a shortcut for `xxx.map do {|sth| sth.method}`) this gives

```
gus = ProjectExternalTeam.where(account_id: 1).map(&:guest)
```

However, see @Gen answer for an optimised DB query.

Answer (score 1):

Your User model supposed to have has_many/has_one relationships to ProjectExternalTeam. So you want to extract users and join your query with ProjectExternalTeam. Something like:

User.joins(:project_external_teams).where("project_external_teams.account_id = ?", 1) [optional ... the rest of the conditions by member_id]

If you need an array at the end just add .to_a.

So, just first try:

User.joins(:project_external_teams).where("project_external_teams.account_id = ?", 1).to_a

and see what you get.